# compiling errors - numeric constant

Tags: c

I keep getting the following compilation errors in my program. I'm suppose to write a program which uses the array `p[]`, which is passed to a function that calculates the polynomial of the nth degree (which is set to 5 below) and returns the value.

My errors are as follows:

> poly.c:4:39: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
>
> poly.c:16:39: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant

My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

double eval(double p[], double x, int N)

int main()
{
    double p[N+1] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    double x;
    printf("what value of x would you like?: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    p[N+1] = eval(p[], x, n);
    printf("%lf", p[N+1]);
}

double eval(double p[], double x, int N)
{
    double y;
    y = x^(p[N+1]);
    return y;
}
```

Comment: N = 5; then N+1=6, so you declare an array of length 6 and initialize it with a literal array of length 5.

Comment: p[N+1] was given in the question, i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @user1304516 He's saying that you're declaring p to be an array of 6 elements, but you're only putting 5 elements into the array (0, 1, 2, 3 and 4).

Answer (score 6):

After the preprocessor is done, your code looks like:

```
double eval(double p[], double x, int 5)
```

So there's still the missing `;` at the end of that line, and that `5` makes no sense there.

Don't define such short macro names, and don't have formal parameter names that are also `#define`. Make sure you only use `N` in all your code where the global constant is meant.

Also, to pass the `p` array as a parameter, just say `p`, not `p[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define N 5

double eval(double p[], double x, int N)
```

Since you #defined N to be 5, the above will look like this after preprocessing:

```
double eval(double p[], double x, int 5)
```

Obviously that's wrong. Also function declarations need to be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: how can i declare the function with a semi colon? wouldn't that produce more syntax?

Comment: @user1304516 I don't understand that question.

Comment: well, you say i need to add a semi colon, where should i add this semi colon :\. (sorry i am completely useless at programming)

Comment: @user1304516 After the function declaration. `double eval(bla, bla);`. A function signature has to either be followed by an opening `{` (in case of a function definition) or by a semicolon (in case of a function declaration).